# Check excel cells

Tags: c#

I need to check if excel cell is empty, null or whitespace (in case there is some string in it). This code should work, but it takes every cell (empty or not) and puts it in rowArray (i guarantee there shouldnt be more than 20 values in this:

```
object[] rowArray = new object[20];

for (int i = 4; i < 38; i++)
{
    excelRange = (Excel.Range)excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelRange.Text.ToString()))
    {
        int j = i - 4;
        rowArray[j]= excelRange.Text.ToString();
    }                    
}
```

Comment: What are some of the values of your cells? Are they a single spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check with *NULL* and whitespace in the string then you can use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which indicates 
*whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.*

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(excelRange.Text.ToString()))
{
   int j = i - 4;
   rowArray[j]= excelRange.Text.ToString();
}
```